# Python Anchors to validate specific characters in beginning and in the end

Tags: python, regex

My example text is

```
A 12324567#JAIEKLLIMdata B
```

and trying to extract string which begins with A and ends with B

my regex is

```
"\AA [A-Za-z0-9]\ZB"
```

or

```
"^A[A-Za-z0-9]B$"
```

I get a no match found when trying run this regex. Any suggestions where i am going wrong?

Comment: Did you really put the `B` after the `\Z`, or is that a copy/paste error? Also, don't forget to use raw strings for regexes (at least if they contain backslashes).

Answer (score 2):

Your second regex almost works, but it only works if the string is exactly three characters long. Try

```
"^A[A-Za-z0-9 #]*B$"
```

(you also need to include `#` and `space` in the character class).